# Can I now replicate an encrypted RDS instance to another region?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, amazon-rds

RDS offers encryption at rest, but this is incompatible with cross-region replication. The documentation states:

> Because KMS encryption keys are specific to the region that they are created in, you cannot copy an encrypted snapshot from one region to another or replicate encrypted DB instances across regions.

However, [it is now possible to upload a custom KMS master key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-bring-your-own-keys-with-aws-key-management-service/). If I generate my own master key and upload it to both eu-west-1 and eu-central-1, is it possible to is it possible to replicate an encrypted RDS instance across regions?

The documentation does not say anything about this scenario. It's possible that it's now technically possible but the API does not permit it.

Comment: Spin up a couple of spot instances, try it and see.

Comment: I guess I'll do that if I have time this week. I was hoping that someone might have had the same thought and already knew.

Comment: Won't RDS check the key ID? It is possible to upload the same key to two regions but they will have different key ids and RDS will refuse to use it. A one character change could fix it (comment out that check ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[I asked this question on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=737685), and got an answer from someone at Amazon:

> As you noted, this is now technically possible but the RDS API does not yet support it. We are working on it but have not announced a release date. Stay tuned.

This is excellent news - soon we won't have to choose between one or the other.